# How to undo change in svg element once you cilck outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now, I have all svg elements with the class "intermandibularis" (there are two) change to a white fill at 50% opacity when you click either of them.

How do I go about making it so that if you click anywhere, the fill opacity goes back to 0, and then you can redo that all over again?

This is what I have:

```js
function homHighlight(highlightClass){
 let allOfSameLabel = document.getElementsByClassName(highlightClass);

 for (let i = 0; i < allOfSameLabel.length; i++) {
  allOfSameLabel[i].style.fill = "#ffffff";
  allOfSameLabel[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Left column -->
 <div class='diagram' style="width:calc(50% - 49px); float:left; height: 85%; background-image: url(Images/mudpuppy_sideview.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain;" id="leftCol">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.1.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 612;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
   .tooltip{opacity:0;fill:#FFFFFF;}
  </style>

  <path id="mud_intermandibularis" class="tooltip intermandibularis" title="Intermandibularis" onclick="homHighlight('intermandibularis')" d=" M185.78,232.53c-3.77-6.28-32.12,3.11-42.47,5.87c-10.36,2.76-39.02,8.98-41.44,14.5
   c-1.78,4.07,43.88,31.14,67.86,31.42c8.58,0.1,11.4-8.12,12.78-17.61C183.19,261.95,190.96,241.16,185.78,232.53z"/>
  <path id="mud_levator_mandibulae_externus" class="tooltip" title ="Levator mandibulae externus" d="M139.76,287.52c6.37-3.09,21.24-4.4,27.19,0
   c5.96,4.4,32.63,21.76,38.07,24.35s33.93,16.32,32.37,23.05c-1.55,6.73-20.46,17.09-39.11,11.14
   c-18.65-5.96-77.96-20.65-81.06-29.75l31.86,6.18c0,0-17.61-4.14-19.94-12.17C126.81,302.28,131.22,291.66,139.76,287.52z"/>
  <path id="mud_branchiohyoideus" class="tooltip" title="Branchiohyoideus" d="M180.94,290.11c-1.61-6.62,26.68-30.82,31.34-33.93c4.66-3.11,30.82-13.73,35.48-11.4
   c4.66,2.33,15.8,35.22,17.09,45.32c1.29,10.1,6.47,23.83,9.06,28.23c2.59,4.4,12.69,15.8,1.81,17.61c-10.88,1.81-30.04,6.73-32.89,0
   c-2.85-6.73-18.91-16.83-26.94-21.5S183.27,299.69,180.94,290.11z"/>
  <path id="mud_interhyoideus" class="tooltip" title="Interhyoideus" d="M213.06,219.4c-5.67,0.65-21.76,9.58-23.05,16.32c-1.29,6.73-4.4,19.3-5.18,21.56
   c-0.78,2.26-1.81,20.14-1.04,20.39c0.78,0.26,20.46-19.68,23.83-22.01c3.37-2.33,28.61-11.4,29.85-12.43
   c1.23-1.04-9.38-6.73-10.94-10.36S222.12,218.37,213.06,219.4z"/>
  <path id="mud_procoracohumeralis" class="tooltip" title="Procoracohumeralis" d="M256.31,249.96c-2.08,1.97,4.4,10.62,27.71,15.8c23.31,5.18,69.67,2.07,82.36-3.11
   c12.69-5.18,27.59-13.61,29.98-18.2c2.39-4.59-27.13-3.29-34.13-3.81c-6.99-0.52-30.04-4.4-41.7-2.85
   c-11.65,1.55-47.91,9.06-50.5,9.06C267.45,246.86,261.23,245.3,256.31,249.96z"/>
  </svg>

 </div>

 <!-- Right column -->
 <div class="diagram" style="width:calc(50% - 49px); float:right; height: 85%; background-image: url(Images/shark_sideview.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain;">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.1.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 612;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
   .tooltip{opacity:0;fill:#FFFFFF;}
  </style>
  <path id="shark_intermandibularis" class="tooltip intermandibularis" title="Intermandibularis" onclick="homHighlight('intermandibularis')" d="M248.8,325.07c0,0-4.14,4.92-10.36,5.96c-6.22,1.04-18.39,0-18.39,0
   s8.55,13.47,22.01,15.28c13.47,1.81,49.73-2.59,50.24-6.47S251.39,325.33,248.8,325.07z"/>
  <path id="shark_adductor_mandibulae" class="tooltip" title="Adductor mandibulae" d="M238.78,286.57c0,0-6.22-13.12-16.92-13.64c-10.71-0.52-21.76,4.83-24.35,17.78
   c-2.59,12.95,6.56,26.24,9.15,30.04c2.59,3.8,9.67,8.29,13.38,8.98c3.71,0.69,23.4,2.59,29.44-6.91s2.76-24.35,0-27.8
   S241.03,287.78,238.78,286.57z"/>
  <path id="shark_x32_nd_dorsal_constrictor" class="tooltip" title="2nd dorsal constrictor" d="M247.76,288.99c0,0-5.87-3.45-6.91-5.01c-1.04-1.55-5.53-9.22-9.15-11.08
   s-16.75-1.87-16.75-1.87s9.69-9.5,10.02-12.6c0.34-3.11,11.39-23.48,19.67-27.28c8.29-3.8,29.7-7.6,41.78,1.04
   c0,0-14.68,19.51-16.06,23.65C269,259.98,258.47,283.63,247.76,288.99z"/>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go about ti in rather a different way than you've proposed. Where you have a bunch of event listeners on the paths themselves, I've just put a listener on each of the svgs.
When fired, it checks for the tagName of the element that was clicked. If it's not a path, then nothing valid was chosen, so remove the style from all paths. If on the other hand, the clicked element was a path, we get the class name from it, remove "tooltip " and then apply styling to all paths that match, removing it from all that dont at the same time.

Oh, and I removed the inline event handlers from the paths also - they're now attached with js to the whole image.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let svgsOnPage = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('svg'));
  svgsOnPage.forEach(svg => svg.addEventListener('click', onSvgClick, false));
}

function onSvgClick(evt) {
  let clickedElement = event.target;
  if (clickedElement.tagName == 'path') {
    let classToHighlight = Array.from(clickedElement.classList).join(' ').replace('tooltip ', '');
    let pathElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('path'));
    pathElems.forEach(
      path => {
        if (path.classList.contains(classToHighlight)) {
          path.style.fill = 'white';
          path.style.opacity = "0.5";
        } else {
          path.style = '';
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    let paths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('path'));
    paths.forEach(path => {
      path.style = '';
    });
  }
}
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #555;
  /* used since the linked files aren't avail */
}
```

```html
<!-- Left column -->
<div class='diagram' style="width:calc(50% - 49px); float:left; height: 85%; background-image: url(Images/mudpuppy_sideview.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain;" id="leftCol">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.1.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 612;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
   .tooltip{opacity:0;fill:#FFFFFF;}
  </style>

  <path id="mud_intermandibularis" class="tooltip intermandibularis" title="Intermandibularis" d="M185.78,232.53c-3.77-6.28-32.12,3.11-42.47,5.87c-10.36,2.76-39.02,8.98-41.44,14.5
   c-1.78,4.07,43.88,31.14,67.86,31.42c8.58,0.1,11.4-8.12,12.78-17.61C183.19,261.95,190.96,241.16,185.78,232.53z"/>
  <path id="mud_levator_mandibulae_externus" class="tooltip" title ="Levator mandibulae externus" d="M139.76,287.52c6.37-3.09,21.24-4.4,27.19,0
   c5.96,4.4,32.63,21.76,38.07,24.35s33.93,16.32,32.37,23.05c-1.55,6.73-20.46,17.09-39.11,11.14
   c-18.65-5.96-77.96-20.65-81.06-29.75l31.86,6.18c0,0-17.61-4.14-19.94-12.17C126.81,302.28,131.22,291.66,139.76,287.52z"/>
  <path id="mud_branchiohyoideus" class="tooltip" title="Branchiohyoideus" d="M180.94,290.11c-1.61-6.62,26.68-30.82,31.34-33.93c4.66-3.11,30.82-13.73,35.48-11.4
   c4.66,2.33,15.8,35.22,17.09,45.32c1.29,10.1,6.47,23.83,9.06,28.23c2.59,4.4,12.69,15.8,1.81,17.61c-10.88,1.81-30.04,6.73-32.89,0
   c-2.85-6.73-18.91-16.83-26.94-21.5S183.27,299.69,180.94,290.11z"/>
  <path id="mud_interhyoideus" class="tooltip" title="Interhyoideus" d="M213.06,219.4c-5.67,0.65-21.76,9.58-23.05,16.32c-1.29,6.73-4.4,19.3-5.18,21.56
   c-0.78,2.26-1.81,20.14-1.04,20.39c0.78,0.26,20.46-19.68,23.83-22.01c3.37-2.33,28.61-11.4,29.85-12.43
   c1.23-1.04-9.38-6.73-10.94-10.36S222.12,218.37,213.06,219.4z"/>
  <path id="mud_procoracohumeralis" class="tooltip" title="Procoracohumeralis" d="M256.31,249.96c-2.08,1.97,4.4,10.62,27.71,15.8c23.31,5.18,69.67,2.07,82.36-3.11
   c12.69-5.18,27.59-13.61,29.98-18.2c2.39-4.59-27.13-3.29-34.13-3.81c-6.99-0.52-30.04-4.4-41.7-2.85
   c-11.65,1.55-47.91,9.06-50.5,9.06C267.45,246.86,261.23,245.3,256.31,249.96z"/>
  </svg>

</div>

<!-- Right column -->
<div class="diagram" style="width:calc(50% - 49px); float:right; height: 85%; background-image: url(Images/shark_sideview.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain;">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.1.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 792 612;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
   .tooltip{opacity:0;fill:#FFFFFF;}
  </style>
  <path id="shark_intermandibularis" class="tooltip intermandibularis" title="Intermandibularis" d="M248.8,325.07c0,0-4.14,4.92-10.36,5.96c-6.22,1.04-18.39,0-18.39,0
   s8.55,13.47,22.01,15.28c13.47,1.81,49.73-2.59,50.24-6.47S251.39,325.33,248.8,325.07z"/>
  <path id="shark_adductor_mandibulae" class="tooltip" title="Adductor mandibulae" d="M238.78,286.57c0,0-6.22-13.12-16.92-13.64c-10.71-0.52-21.76,4.83-24.35,17.78
   c-2.59,12.95,6.56,26.24,9.15,30.04c2.59,3.8,9.67,8.29,13.38,8.98c3.71,0.69,23.4,2.59,29.44-6.91s2.76-24.35,0-27.8
   S241.03,287.78,238.78,286.57z"/>
  <path id="shark_x32_nd_dorsal_constrictor" class="tooltip" title="2nd dorsal constrictor" d="M247.76,288.99c0,0-5.87-3.45-6.91-5.01c-1.04-1.55-5.53-9.22-9.15-11.08
   s-16.75-1.87-16.75-1.87s9.69-9.5,10.02-12.6c0.34-3.11,11.39-23.48,19.67-27.28c8.29-3.8,29.7-7.6,41.78,1.04
   c0,0-14.68,19.51-16.06,23.65C269,259.98,258.47,283.63,247.76,288.99z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```